# C++ STL: How to iterate vector while requiring access to element and its index?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iteration

I frequently find myself requiring to iterate over **STL vectors**. While I am doing this I require access to both the vector **element** and its **index**.

I used to do this as:

```
typedef std::vector<Foo> FooVec;
typedef FooVec::iterator FooVecIter;

FooVec fooVec;
int index = 0;
for (FooVecIter i = fooVec.begin(); i != fooVec.end(); ++i, ++index)
{
    Foo& foo = *i;
    if (foo.somethingIsTrue()) // True for most elements
        std::cout << index << ": " << foo << std::endl;
}
```

After discovering **BOOST_FOREACH**, I shortened this to:

```
typedef std::vector<Foo> FooVec;

FooVec fooVec;
int index = -1;
BOOST_FOREACH( Foo& foo, fooVec )
{
    ++index;
    if (foo.somethingIsTrue()) // True for most elements
        std::cout << index << ": " << foo << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a better or more elegant way to iterate over STL vectors when both reference to the vector element and its index is required?

I am aware of the alternative: `for (int i = 0; i < fooVec.size(); ++i)` But I keep reading about how it is not a good practice to iterate over STL containers like this.

Answer (score 8):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    elem = vec[i];
```

Vectors are a thin wrapper over C arrays; whether you use iterators or indexes, it's just as fast. Other data structures are not so forgiving though, for example std::list.

Comment: Actually this is not necessarily the best. Random access is less prone to cache optimization then iteration -- iteration carries the additional information that data will be accessed sequentially what allows modern optimizers to prepare the cache and save us from the oh-so-costly cache misses. Run a test comparing non-trivial vector iteration on different architectures -- you might be surprised.

Comment: That is interesting, but can you provide a source (link or keywords)? For which compiler is that the case? Generally recognizing sequential access in loop shouldn't be harder for compiler than recognizing std iterators. I can think of couple other reasons to explain why iteration can be faster, depending on vector implementation.

Comment: In fact, I just checked Intel compiler documentation and, while it lists plenty of cache access optimizations for loops, there is not a single mention (under any name) of stl flavor of iteration. In the best case, stl iteration will be optimized into loop, then the same techniques will apply.

Comment: Actually assuming sequential access with iterators is not possible as I can easily advance by any number of element I want with a random access iterator. It is no more optimizable than an index; a vector iterator is practically a plain pointer. Whether you increment the pointer each iteration or you add i to it, it's still a simple add instruction.

Answer (score 7):

You can always compute the index in the loop:

```
std::size_t index = std::distance(fooVec.begin(), i);
```

For a vector, this is quite likely to be implemented as a single pointer subtraction operation, so it's not particularly expensive.

Comment: However, for other data structures it can get quite expensive.

Comment: @iconiK:  I don't disagree with that.

Comment: I think it's better to increment the index in the loop if you iterate over all the elements of a generic container. That way you don't loop around a list 3 million times calculating an index.

Comment: @iconiK:  Accessing an element via subscript should not be faster than computing the distance from the beginning of the container to a given iterator.  There might be corner cases, but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: `std::distance` for *random access iterators* like `std::vector` is O(1), being just a pointer subtraction, but for other less flexible iterators (e.g. those of `std::list`) it's an O(N) operation, and it is better to not compute `index` again and again in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Elegance is in the eye of the beholder, however do remember pointer/iterator arithmetics :)

```
for (FooVecIter i = fooVec.begin(); i != fooVec.end(); ++i)
{
    Foo& foo = *i;
    if (foo.somethingIsTrue()) // True for most elements
        std::cout << i - fooVec.begin() << ": " << foo << std::endl;
}
```

The up-side compared to the distance method is that you won't mistakenly do this for a non-random_access_iterator, so you'll always be in *O(1)*.

Comment: Why you you subtracting a FooVecIter from a Foo in i - fooVec.begin() // makes no sense.

Comment: Okay, it works, though I don't understand how exactly, as it's weird (but then, I'm no iterator wizard): http://codepad.org/ycqlJxU5

Comment: @iconiK, both are FooVectIter

Comment: @Kornel:  I agree; enforcing that the iterator is random-accessible is often a better idea than using distance.

Comment: @Kornel, ahh, my bad, I thought I saw foo - fooVec.begin(0). Being tired is not good for programming, I tell you that!

Answer (score 3):

For the specific question:

> ```
> Is there a better or more elegant way to iterate over STL vectors
> when both reference to the vector element and its index is required?
> ```

IMHO,

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < fooVec.size(); ++i) {
    Foo & foo = fooVec[i];        // if 'foo' is to be modified
    Foo const& foo = fooVec[i];   // if 'foo' is to be NOT modified
}
```

is the most simple and elegant solution. Per the requirements of the question, using an iterator is not required.

Comment: You can't rebind a reference.